# Movement of the satellites of the planets . . .

Tags: planet, natural-satellites

Is the movement of the satellites (moons) of a planet coplanar, like the planets being coplanar around the local Sun?

Comment: With coplanar, do you mean the inclination? No, not necessarily; for instance the smaller jovian moon can have inclinations of >160°. See en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Jupiter

Comment: By coplanar, I mean, the orbits are on the same plane.  For example, the orbits of the planets moving around the sun are coplanar

Comment: Well, Mercury has an inclination of ~7° and Venus about 3.4°; if that's coplanar, then the answer is no. Especially smaller moons can have very high inclinations.

Answer (score 1):

Inner moon orbits tend to low inclinations with regard to planet's equatorial plane. Charon is an exception to this general rule. Nineplanets.org has a [nice data base](http://nineplanets.org/data.html).